# TP in lib/script.js vs. assetRegistry from composer-client to update an asset?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm looking at knowing, In order to update a asset,

When should I need to write Transaction in `lib/script.js`

vs.

when should I be using `composer-client` code using `bizNetworkConnection.getAssetRegistry`?

I see that I cant use the feature of event emission in later case, Is there any other reason why I should be using it?

Please help me know.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing about writing a Transaction is that it becomes part of the **Agreed Smart Contract**.  So the creation of one or more assets or participants in the same transaction with the associated logic is agreed.  This Transaction is a class and can have a specific ACL rule associated with it (also in the smart contract), whereas if you use composer-client you would add individual assets or participants using a generic system transaction AddAsset or AddParticipant.

So writing your code in a Transaction provides a 'better' Blockchain app with a stronger Smart Contract and improved security.

Comment: makes sense! Thank you.